# How to declare a list inside a Scheme function?

Tags: scheme

I want to declare an empty list inside a scheme function. To make this happen, i use let. I know the structure of let

```
(let (name1 value1) (name2 value2)...)
```

But when i apply this into my function

```
(let (new-list '()))
```

i get an error which says " let: expected a binding with a variable and an expression, but found something else"
How can i fix it, any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let expects a list of bindings and an s-expression.

`(let ((name1 value1) (name2 value2) ...) expression-to-evaluate-with-the-bindings)`

You need another layer of parentheses.

RTFM at [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_394) for the gory details.